# .htaccess force trailing slash but exclude images

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using Wordpress and I am having an issue with including the trailing `/` on my urls.  I have used `RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]` however its adding an extra slash onto my images and making them not found.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is definitely to remove all url containing a dot

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna exclude image from this mentioned rule , your code will be like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=302]
```

So , by this condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]` you will be able to override any image with `gif,jpe,jpeg or png` extension from the rule of the last line